# Can`t use delay/sleep functions in C

Tags: c

I am trying to use delay/sleep function in my code, but it gives me the same error every time: "Undefined reference to `whateverIput`"

By `whateverIput` i mean sleep/Sleep/delay/Delay.

I included both dos.h and time.h libraries (next to my normal stdio.h and stdlib.h libraries) still nothing.

I searched the web before I posted, but I just can`t find the solution.

Platform: Codeblocks 13.12 with GNU GCC Compiler on Windows 8.1

#### Code

```
#include<dos.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

int main() {
    for(;;){
        puts("bla");
        Sleep(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Most likely, you have multiple files like `blah.c` and `foo.c` and you're not passing them to your compiler correctly. You'll need to include more information about how you compile your files and exactly what is in those files. And you should try and make a reduced test case that exhibits this problem.

Comment: how about `<sys/time.h>` or `<unistd.h>` ?

Comment: @AustinMullins: So the error in that question is "Implict Declaration". We're getting a linker error here. Although it's always possible that he's getting both and just didn't tell us about the first one.

Comment: I tried to isolate the problem, by creating a completely separated file test1.c in a separate folder, where I try to call just those functions in main() ... doesn`t work.

Comment: @CholaTech: What does "doesn't work" mean. Presumably you have reduced your code to ~20 lines of code? And you presumably have some expected response from the compiler / code. And presumably the code / compiler gave you a different response. Adding all of that to your question would make this an __excellent__ question. Your current question is __terrible__.

Comment: @BillLynch true. It's probably a library linking issue.

Comment: @CholaTech: `unistd.h` is a POSIX header. So it is found on Linux (among others) and won't be found under Windows. And thus is probably an unhelpful suggestion for you.

Comment: You might try using `find` or `grep` to search through all the .h files for your compiler for `sleep` or `delay`.

Comment: Maybe you could use macros to define `Sleep()` as POSIX sleep under *nix and `#include <windows.h>` on Windows.

Comment: @BillLynch "Doesn't work" means that it keeps giving me the same error.
I'm not planing on using unistd.h since I'm not using POSIX header  since I'm not on Linux, therefore let's not even go in that direction.

Now is there anything I can do to make that delay work? (as you can see, my code is really simple, there is nothing to break there, it's just a linker issue)

Comment: I got the answer: #include<Windows.h>

Comment: @CholaTech: Your code produces __TWO__ notifications. Please show us both of them in the future. http://imgur.com/M8IclMS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What functions you use to make a thread sleep are dependent on the operating system you are using.
For Windows 8.1 you need to include Windows.h

```
#include<Windows.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

int main() {
    for(;;){
        puts("bla");
        Sleep(1000); // Will sleep for 1 second
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Documentation for this is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: What the hell is `Sleep()` ???  is it standard? If somebody is waiting for a whole second, isn't better to use `sleep(1);` ???

Comment: Sleep is the windows sleep command. Remember task delaying and the like is os specific. POSIX is an effort to make that a standard, but the libraries don't automatically exist on every windows computer.

Comment: sleep() is older than posix... It appears in K&R ed. 1.

Comment: Yes. It is in unistd.h... which is a unix header. Which helps a windows user not at all.

Comment: being part of unix doesn't mean not being part of windows.  The first time I used that function was with Turbo C (a Borland product running on Microsoft's MS-DOS) v1.0 probably in the 80's.  It appears in Kernighan & Ritchie's "The C programming language" first edition (the one that doesn't cover ANSI-C) and there, it's not linked with any header file (neither unix nor windows/ms-dos)